# Make an object visible on form field input

Tags: object

I'm adding a CAPTCHA object to my website to a single field form for users to sign up for our newsletter. I have everything working as desired but what I'd really like to do is hide the captcha object until a user begins to type their email address into the form field. How would I accomplish this?